# Are local variables to method being shared by threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

This question is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979106/does-runnable-share-the-data-structure-if-they-are-getting-changed).

What if in that question `AbcRunnable` would have a member variable as a class which only has methods which are getting called from `Runnable`. E.g.

```
public class AbcRunnable implements Runnable
{
     private final AbcSupplier supplier;

     public void run() {

        List<Message> messages = supplier.get();
     }
}

public class AbcSupplier implements Supplier<List<Message>> {

     public List<Message> get() {
         List<Message> list = new ArrayList<>();
         /*
          Some operations on list
         */
         return list
     }
}
```

So, in this case, if 2 threads are sharing the object of `AbcSupplier` because we are creating only one instance of it. Then, will they also share the local variable list in there? Or they won't be?

I tried running it by myself. To me, it looked like, they are getting shared but not 100% sure.

Comment: How are you initializing the supplier?

Comment: What have you tried to figure it out?

Comment: Local variables are local. There is a separate instance of the list for every invocation of the method, no matter the thread on which that occurs.

Comment: no , both thread will have their own stack , so both thread will have their own separate copy of method , so variable within method wont be shared .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Two threads running `AbcRunnable.run()` won't share the same instance of the list returned by `AbcSupplier.get()`. This is because `get()` creates an `ArrayList` instance every time it runs.

Here's a version that would cause threads to share the same list:

```
public class AbcSupplier implements Supplier<List<Message>> {

     List<Message> list = new ArrayList<>();
     public AbcSupplier() {
         ......
         Some operations on list
         ......
     }

     public List<Message> get() {
         return list;
     }
}
```

In this case, the same `AbcSupplier` instance would return the same `List` instance.